# Declare variable with two interfaces

Tags: java, class, oop, interface, hierarchy

Is there some "best practice" how to declare a variable implementing two interfaces?

Let's say your method needs an object to implement `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` at the same time.

```
void doSomething( BOTH_INTERFACES argument) {
...
}
```

**What do you think is the best way to achieve or simulate this?**

---

I thought of creating a combining interface

```
interface InterfaceAB extends InterfaceA, InterfaceB {}
```

But can I then cast the following object to it?

```
class SomeObject implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {}
```

---

*Other ideas:*

I could do something like:

```
void doSomething( Object argument) {
    if(!(argument instanceof InterfaceA) || !(argument instanceof InterfaceB)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    InterfaceA faceA = (InterfaceA) argument;
    InterfaceB faceB = (InterfaceB) argument;
    // do some stuff with it
}
```

Or perhaps this hideousness:

```
void doSomething( InterfaceA faceA, InterfaceB faceB) {
    if(faceA != faceB) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    // do some stuff with it
}
```

What would you suggest, what do you use / consider the best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do

```
interface InterfaceAB extends InterfaceA, InterfaceB {}
```

And for an implementation

```
class SomeObject implements InterfaceAB {}
```

In reality if you have many subtype you usally have an abstract class that stores some common code. So you would have:

```
class AInterfaceAB implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {}
```

So if you want to skip the container Interface you could use the abstract. Its not super elegant, but practical and has no real drawbacks, other than not using interface.

Different Approach: you could use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) with multiple upper bounds:

```
<T extends InterfaceA&InterfaceB> void doSomething(T argument) {
}
```

Comment: If you're using an interface, in reality you *would* be using `void doSomething(InterfaceAB argument)`, otherwise the interface is useless.

Comment: This looks like a good approach, but I'll wait a bit longer to see if some better idea doesn't show among the answers.

Comment: @A--C - yea you are right I changed that, what I meant was (practical speaking not textbook oop) that I usually often end up with using the specific implementaitons anyway because as the code emerges I need this or that special method and adding all convient/helper methods to interface seems unnecessry

Comment: @for3st If you want to make something abstract and robust (read: API), you have to do it properly - with all the abstraction Java can offer.

Comment: Question about the generics, how would you make a field of this type?

Comment: @MightyPork it seems java can have multiple upper bounds (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034231/how-to-use-multiple-upper-bounds-in-generics) so this would be the approch. Downside seems to be that it is a little strange to read.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
InterfaceA extends BaseAB

InterfaceB extends BaseAB
```

And BaseAB is an interface with EMPTY methods OR common methods.

You can use BaseAB in function like below:

```
void doSomething( BaseAB argument) {

      if (argument instanceof InterfaceA )
      { }
      else
      {}
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but this way I can't be sure the argument implements them both at once, or can I?

Comment: I think if you want that, you have to check like: if ( (arg instanceof A) && (arg instanceof B) { ... }

Comment: This is not a clean solution.